# adding to a list of dictionaries - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I am trying to add a new dict to an existing list of dictionaries which takes a new key and list of values.

My list of dictionary is called "options" and this is what it looks like:

```
[{'powerpoint_color': 'blue', 'client_name': 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'}, 
{'crossbreak': 'profile_julesage', 'chart_layout': '8', 'chart_type': 'pie', 'sort_order': 'desending'}]
```

I'd like to add a new dict to the options but I am unsure how?

I'd like to call my new dict with a Key called "fixed_properties" and it will take a list of strings called "fixed_elements".

I tried something like this:

```
fixed_elements = []

options['fixed_properties'] = fixed_elements
```

But i got this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

This is what I would like the 'options' dict to look like:

```
[{'powerpoint_color': 'blue', 'client_name': 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'}, 
{'crossbreak': 'profile_julesage', 'chart_layout': '8', 'chart_type': 'pie', 'sort_order': 'desending'}
{'fixed_properties': ['q1','q4','q6']}]
```

Any advice please?

Thanks.

Comment: The code you show doesn't produce that error; it will instead give an error about a non-integer index for the list `options`. What did you *actually* try? (Note that `{}` is an empty dict, if what you're actually trying is to append 'q1' etc to it, that obviously won't work.)

Comment: My bad, fixed_elements is an empty list which stores questions which have a fixed property. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `options` is your options list:

```
options.append({'fixed_properties': fixed_elements})
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I did this: options.append({'fixed_props': fixed_elements})

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `options` variable is a list, so `options['fixed_properties']` wouldn't work because you can only reference objects in lists by their index number.

You'd be better off structuring your `options` variable like this:

```
options = {
    "whatever_properties": {
        'powerpoint_color': 'blue',
        'client_name': 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'
    }
}
```

This lets you get whatever properties you want using the `options["whatever_properties"]["powerpoint_color"]` syntax, for instance.

Using this, your code `options["fixed_options"] = fixed_elements` would work.